# Android NFC (ATQB from ISO-14443 Type B tag to phone)

Tags: android, tags, protocols, nfc, iso

My goal is to have an Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Nexus) communicate with a TI TRF7970A card in emulation mode (emulates ISO-14443 type B tag) through NFC.
I understand that the PCD (Android phone) sends out a "REQB" with a given AFI and then which ever PICC's (in my case only PICC is the TI TRF7970 card) that have a matching AFI will send an "ATQB" back to the PCD.

In some TRF7970A firmware the "ATQB" response was set up like so:

```
0x50;   // 
//PUPI   
0x80;   //  PUPI_0  
0x12;   //  PUPI_1  
0x34;   //  PUPI_2  
0x56;   //  PUPI_3  
    //Application DATA  
0x40;   //  APP_0   AFI Telecommunication (Telephone,GSM) All Sub families 1-F    
0xE2;   //  APP_1   CRC_B of the AID (multibyte application identifier code which identifies an application provider or issuer and indicates if the application provider is registered with ISO)  
0xAF;   //  APP_2   CRC_B of the AID  
0x11;   //  APP_3   # of applications (1)  
    //Protocol DATA  
0x80;   //  Data rate capabilities (Same bit rate from PCD to PICC and from PICC to PCD compulsory)  
0x71;   //  Max Frames (128 bytes) / Protocol Type (supports PICC ISO 14443-4)  
0x85;   //  FWI (0b1000 - 8192 ETUs or 77328.6 us) / ADC (0b01 - determines what APP_0-3 are if 0b00 then App data can be anything) / FO (0b01 - CID Supported - used for identification of multiple cards in the Active state)
```

This "ATQB" has the PCD (Android phone) automatically launch the web browser with URL "http://www.Cisco Auth Complete".

Question:
(1) Which field tells the phone to automatically launch the web browser? How can I change that field so that I can manually chose which application acts on the intent?

I've tried looking online to learn how I can manipulate the fields but have had no luck.
I read 3 Type B 14443-4 Smart Cards (MAXIM-MAX66020k-00AA+) with my Android phone and the "ATQB"'s were as follows:

```
Card 1      Card 2      Card 3

0x50        0x50        0x50  
                    //PUPI  
0xd8        0x99        0x1a  
0x60        0x5c        0x61  
0x02        0x02        0x02  
0x00        0x00        0x00  
                    //Application Data 
0x10        0x20        0x10  
0x10        0x00        0x10  
0x11        0x2b        0x11  
0x11        0xe0        0x11  
                    //Protocol Data  
0x00        0x00        0x00    106Kbits/sec  
0x00        0x00        0x00    16 bytes / Not type B -4 complient)  
0x00        0x00        0x00    32 ETUs / Application is proprietary / Nad "nor" CID are supported
```

I tried sending these exact ATQB messages with the TI TRF7970A card but the Android phone still does not act on the "ATQB" response.

Question:
(2) Can you point out a reason why any of these last 3 "ATQB"'s wouldn't be excepted?
(3) What are some legit "ATQB"'s that when sent to my Android phone it will create an intent?
(4) Are there rules I can follow so that my android phone always creates an intent on the "ATQB"'s I respond with from the TI TRF7970A?

If you could direct me to a source that can explain any of this, it would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!
-Derek

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking in the wrong place. The TRF7970A is probably emulating an [NFC Forum Type 4 Tag](http://www.nfc-forum.org/specs/spec_list/#tagtypes), containing an NDEF message.
How this results in an intent is explained at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/nfc/nfc.html

Comment: is there a way to send a different type of tag that doesn't include an NDEF message? I'd like it to allow me to do what I wish with the information instead of it getting read as an NDEF message and then creating an NDEF_DISCOVERED intent and opening the webpage. I

Comment: I am not familiar with the TRF7970A. I imagine that it would be possible to turn off the Type 4 Tag behaviour and just emulate a plain tag or change the content of the NDEF message. Both possibilities would allow you to, for example, start your own app instead of the browser.

Comment: Here is an application note with a detailed explanation: http://www.ti.com/lit/an/slaa512/slaa512.pdf